# DataTables - _fnAjaxDataSrc - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

When I further check debugging and I found that it does passing the json data, here are the screen shots of debugging.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[Demo PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lxlpF5o7u3bxGPT6xcS?p=preview)

```
<html>
<head>
  <link 
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js" data-semver="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>primaryGenreName</th>
        <th>country</th>    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find that `_fnAjaxDataSrc` function [datatables src](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js) . Where is definition of that function?

Comment: ver DataTables 1.10.4: line number 3019

Comment: You are using 1.9.4 version in your example and there isnt definition for that function. :)

Comment: ooops i'm sorry forgot to point to the correct one when I was creating a demo on plkr, let me correct but i'm using 1.10.4 on my local machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing old legacy `datatables` api with new version of datatables.

Use new API:

- [AJAX](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)
- [DATA format](http://datatables.net/manual/data)

I didn't manage to use "Demo PLNKR" example due to cross domain policy of that JSON data source :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple&_=1421706895095. This can
>   be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

**At the end my advice is to :**

Change `sAjaxSource` to `ajax` , `aoColumns` to `columns`, `mData` to `data`...

Take care of JSON format Ajax response that you are getting, map that properly with data column field [example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html). If you are using itunes result it will be something like this :

```
"ajax": {
    "url" : "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple",
    "dataSrc" : "results"
},
"columns": [
 {"data": "artistName"},
 {"data": "collectionName"},
 {"data": "trackName"},
 {"data": "collectionCensoredName"},
 {"data": "trackCensoredName"},
 {"data": "artistViewUrl"},
 ...
]
```

Comment: if you install google chrome extension and it will allows you do cross domain, here is the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: I cant do that right now. Use my answer as starting point for changes :)

Comment: What exactly I have to Change and where?

Comment: @AbuHamzah I wrote that at the end of ma answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem. Fix for this issue is to set 'sAjaxDataProp' to "" (i.e. empty) if you directly want to bind array to your datatable. This is similar to setting datasrc = "" in ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all I needed to do was to set the "columns" parameter, as in the @Nikola Loncar answer, and define a key to the ajax return: Put all the resultant array inside "data" key. Example: {"data": [...]}.